# Dividing integers does not get a result

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, divide

I'm trying to divide 2 integer and get the float results but it does not seem it is working properly. Can you see where am i doing wrong? sscanf part is working, the problem is at the dividing part.

```
char *latitude = "4055,1792.N";
int val1;
int val2;
int val3;
float result;

sscanf ( latitude, "%2d%2d,%4d", &val1, &val2, &val3);
printf("\r\nval1 = %d val2 = %d val3 = %d\r\n",val1,val2,val3);
result = val1 + (float)val2/(float)60 + (float)val3/(float)600000;

printf("\r\nResult = %f\r\n",result);
printf("\r\nEnd\r\n");
```

This code does not result this operation. Here is the output:

```
val1 = 40 val2 = 55 val3 = 1792                                                 

Result =                                                                        

End
```

Comment: You missed something else. Can you put that code inside a main and test ?

Comment: Try postfixing `600000` with `L`: `600000L`

Comment: So it prints nothing at all for the result?  That doesn't seem right.  Also, why all the hard return characters (`\r`)?  You shouldn't need any of those.

Comment: I'm using windows 7. It's not working even if i do the divide operation with numbers smaller then 10. It's not about the function, i'm calling it in main and it succesfully gets there.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Please post the *full* code. Are you getting any compiler warnings?

Comment: What makes you think the divide is the problem?  Try setting `result` to something simple like 1.0 and see if you can print it.  It seems like the problem is that you aren't able to print it.

Comment: @abdullahcinar ok you're on windows 7 but what compiler ? And put that code that you have posted inside a main() function (i.e. post a code which can be compiled and tested). Test it and let us know if it actually doesn't work.

Comment: There is not any compiler warnings, it can print the sscanf result but can not print the divide result. So i think it is the problem.

Comment: Okey, i'm gonna add that soon.

Comment: @abdullahcinar You are ignoring a simple question in a third time. **What compiler are you using???**

Comment: The only thing you seem to have evidence of is that you are unable to print floats using %f.  Prove me wrong.

Comment: You asked many basic questions in short time about much the same subject. stack overflow is no tutorial site. It might be a good idea to first get the basics right before starting a large project. Also, in general, some planing in advance for a non-trivial project is advisable. That way you will see which functionality you need and search the C standard library for helpful functions. Information is available by a simple search.

Comment: Slapping a main around this works for me (RHEL6/gcc).  So I agree this seems to be a compiler issue...

Comment: @Eugene Sorry i had to go out so couldn't answer quick. I didnt know what compiler does my IDE using. I needed to have a look at it. Currently i'm working on psoc creator which uses keil c51 compiler. I'm gonna try to contact with Cypress support to investigate this issue. Sorry for the convenience but i was confused when i couldn't run a program which i'm sure about it, also checked the usafe of this from other stack questions.

Comment: So it is some kind of hardware platform different from PC, as I conclude.

Comment: Insure code has `#include <stdio.h>` else the call to `printf()` is UB.

Comment: Yes i am coding for an embedded platform. Thanks for the information but it already included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which compiler you are using .
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4)

It gives following result .

val1 = 40 val2 = 55 val3 = 1792

Result = 40.919655

Comment: arm gcc 4.9-2015-q-1
Seems like it's about my IDE, i'm trying to solve it with Cypress support. Thanks.